# Unable to access my .scss bundle file from another folder

Tags: css, node.js, angular, sass, angular-cli

I want to retrieve my .scss file which has all the other .scss imported into it (all the other .scss files are imported in the styles.scss).

I've put the path into my angular cli file and the file is still not accessible (no styling is applied on my html element)

**Angular CLI** : from the folder(project) which I'm running on *npm start* (added the  "../webstyles/src/styles.scss" path from the folder which I want to access)

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "app/cms/demo.json"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "cb",
      "styles": [
        "../webstyles/src/styles.scss"
      ],
```

**The error I get is: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve the path... in that project.**

I'm sorry I can't post the folder tree but I checked it multiple times and don't think I made a mistake here

What are my options?

Comment: can you add folder tree

Comment: What's the best way to do that, printscreen?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't I'm not authorized...

Comment: press "PrtSc" key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path `"../webstyles/src/styles.scss"` is just wrong

Use that `"styles"` config if your `styles.scss` is outside `src` folder:

```
"styles": [
        "../webstyles/styles.scss"
      ],
```

If your styles is inside `src` folder then use that:

```
"styles": [
            "styles.scss"
          ],
```

or

```
"styles": [
        "webstyles/styles.scss"
      ],
```

It is really depends on your folder structure, and I can't clearly see that based on your question.

> Every time you changing/saving the `.angular-cli.json` restart `npm start/ng serve`

Comment: Thanks for the answer I really wish it was but the .scss is located in the src XD,

Comment: Is there anything else I should change in order to make this working...

Comment: what is the exact path to `styles.scss` ? check in your file manager, file explorer, etc

Comment: btw, every time you change the `.angular-cli.json` restart `npm start/ng serve`

Comment: Should have gone up once more... Tnx for the navigation and help... sorry for waisting your time for that.

Comment: The problems is the that the current folder which angular.cli is using is the src folder! in this is why I needed to go up once more.